# Select JSON in postgres 9.5

Tags: json, postgresql

There is a column "fields" in my table.
It contains something like this:

```
{"creative_url": {"required": true, "data_type": "string"}}
```

or

```
{"creative_name_field": {"required": false, "data_type": "integer"}}
```

So, different keys in main dict.

I want to select all rows with:

```
"required": true
```

Trying something like :

```
select *
from my_table
where fields @> '{"required":true}'
```

But it shows me nothing (0 rows found).

[Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) doesn't give me any other method to do this.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@>` operator checks only at top level.
You can use the `jsonb_object_keys` function to get the top level keys of your jsonb objects (use `json_object_keys` if you're using the `json` type instead).

```
WITH j(json) AS (
  VALUES 
    ('{"creative_url": {"required": true, "data_type": "string"}}'::jsonb),
    ('{"creative_name_field": {"required": false, "data_type": "integer"}}')
)
SELECT 
  json,
  json->k @> '{"required": true}' AS is_required
FROM j, jsonb_object_keys(json) s(k)
;
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│                                 json                                 │ is_required │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│ {"creative_url": {"required": true, "data_type": "string"}}          │ t           │
│ {"creative_name_field": {"required": false, "data_type": "integer"}} │ f           │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────┘
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Really difficult to understand this query) But it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Though answer is accepted already and OP is satisfied with answer but I am still adding solution to those who may need helps.
It seems you have two level search in the db with `json` object column.
The simplest way to get the record is

```
select * from my_table where fields->'creative_name_field'->>'required'='true' OR fields->'creative_url'->>'required'='true';
```

There is other way of doing this but I haven't tested it

```
select * from my_table where fields->{'creative_url', 'creative_name_field'}->>'required'='true';
```

There is one catch here is to use the parent key before the `is_required` sub-key check.
Hope This will help.

Comment: This example will not work if I want to select all fields ('creative_name_field' and 'creative_url') with `required='true'`

Comment: Oh I missed the point `So, different keys in main dict.`. But now I have corrected the solution.